# Setting a Dynamic Href in Hyperlink in MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, webforms

The following will work:

```
<%  if (Sql.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Current.Application["CONFIG.SHOW_REPORTING_LINK"])) 
    { 
%>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hypReporting" ForeColor="white" Text='Reporting' NavigateUrl="#" CssClass="myAreaLink" Runat="server" />
           &nbsp;<font color="white">|</font>&nbsp; 
<% 
    } 
%>
```

However, I need a dynamic link, instead of a static one.  I tried this:

```
<%  if (Sql.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Current.Application["CONFIG.SHOW_REPORTING_LINK"])) 
    { 
%>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hypReporting" ForeColor="white" Text='Reporting' NavigateUrl="<%# Eval(HttpContext.Current.Application["CONFIG.REPORTING_URL"]) %>" CssClass="myAreaLink" Runat="server" />
           &nbsp;<font color="white">|</font>&nbsp; 
<% 
    } 
%>
```

But, it gives me an error that says, "The server tag is not well formed."

I would normally do this from codebehind, but there is no codebehind in a .master file, right?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the double quotes in the NavigateUrl that are causing the bad server tag. It should be:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# Eval(HttpContext.Current.Application["CONFIG.REPORTING_URL"]) %>'
```

And you should get rid of that `<font>` tag and just use CSS. That tag is deprecated.

Yes there is code-behind in the master page file (right-click -> view code; or in the Solution Explorer, ensure that "Show All Files" is clicked). It would likely be easier/cleaner to do it there.

Comment: Thanks, this works for my problem.  But, the code-behind thing doesn't work.  I had already tried right-clicking and selecting View Code; it just brings up the same .master page.  Here is a screenshot of what I see when I click Show All Files http://picturepush.com/public/12582556

Comment: @user1477388 hmm... I guess maybe you set it up not to have a code behind because you are doing all of the code on the page itself? As in, the top line doesn't have the CodeBehind reference, like `<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeBehind="Site1.master.vb"...`?

Comment: I guess it does, now that you mention it, `CodeBehind="DefaultView.master.cs"`.  Maybe if I find that file it would be in there...

Comment: If it does reference that file, then it should be there. Though considering your screenshot, that is definitely strange.